# SQL One-To-Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, one-to-many

I'm new to `SQL` and I want to create a `One-To-Many` relationship between two tables.
I have these two tables created with the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CustomerId)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    TotalDue FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderId),
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId)
);
```

However even though I set `CustomerId` as a foreign key for the `Orders` table I'm still able to add rows in the `Orders` table with a `CustomerId` that is not present in the `Customers` table. Why is that and how can I create a real link between the tables?

This is what the tables look like(copy/paste from my `mysql` client):

```
mysql> select * from Customers;
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
| CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | Email             | Address                |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
|          1 | Jacks     | James    | james98@yahoo.com | Str. Moony, No. 9      |
|          2 | Mock      | Grad     | rrfuX@yahoo.com   | Str. Mars, No. 91      |
|          3 | James     | Geremy   | gv@yahoo.com      | Str. Monday, No. 12    |
|          4 | Joana     | Joan     | iiogn@yahoo.com   | Str. Comete, No. 19    |
|          5 | Granicer  | James    | gtuawr@yahoo.com  | Str. Sydney, No. 651   |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Orders;
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
| OrderId | Date       | Quantity | TotalDue | CustomerId |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
|       1 | 2014-01-09 |       10 |      340 |          3 |
|       2 | 2014-01-09 |        1 |       50 |          3 |
|       3 | 2014-01-09 |       11 |       55 |          5 |
|       4 | 2014-01-09 |       11 |       55 |         51 |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see `OrderId` 4 contains a customer with `CustomerId` 51 which is not in the `Customers` table.

Comment: Are you using INNODB engine for the tables?

Comment: @raj I don't know, I'm pretty new to databases...how can I find out?

Comment: "show table status" should give you the engine types

Comment: @raj Thanks for the reply. No, it seems like I'm using `MyISAM`. Could this be the cause?

Comment: myisam does not support foreign keys

Comment: @raj waw...this is interesting to know. Is it possible to change the engine? and another question comes into my mind..."How can it be that it does not support foreign keys when databases are all about table relations?"...

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and started using the web client of MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the storage engine...change your query to...

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    TotalDue FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderId),
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! yes, there is an error there but i recreated the example with the error corrected and i don't think that's the case. I still can do that.... here's my mysql client output: http://pastebin.com/naNP0RMq

Answer (score 0):

Use InnoDB for the table engine.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I tried using `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;` but it still allows me to add invalid `CustomerId`...here is what I did http://pastebin.com/5mXmCwHM and in the end I can add a customer with id 9, when I have only 5 customers in the `Customers` table...did I do something wrong or altering the table won't work?

Comment: When you try to insert into orders after changing it to InnDB, you should get "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". Check again the engine after you ran the alter engine query

Comment: I checked and the Engine is InnoDB... http://pastebin.com/xCPm1Q6U Is InnoDB supporting foreign keys?